# Comparing strings multiple times

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, hash, compare

I'm generating random scripts, but I have to guarantee that each new one is unique (hasn't been repeated before). So basically each script that has already been generated gets compared against every new script.

Instead of just using normal string compare, I'm thinking there must be a way to hash each new script so that comparison will be faster.

Any ideas on how to hash strings to make multiple comparisons faster?

Comment: you need to make sure that all string are the same ?

Comment: "each new one is unique" so the opposite of what you said :)

Comment: Have you tried HashSet<String> or Dictionary<String,String> for lookups (O(1) lookup speed) with the script digest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `HashSet<String>`

> The HashSetclass provides high performance set operations. A set is
>   a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements
>   are in no particular order.

```
HashSet<string> scripts = new HashSet<string>();

string generated_script = "some_text";

if (!scripts.Contains(generated_script)) // is HashSet<String> dont contains your string already then you can add it
{
    scripts.Add(generated_script);
}
```

---

Also, You can check for existence of `duplicate items` in the array.
But this may not be very efficient as compared to `HashSet<String>`

```
string[] array = new[] {"demo", "demo", "demo"};
string compareWith = "demo";

int duplicates_count = array.GroupBy(x => x).Count(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: The OP appears to be looking for file hashing.. not string comparison.

Comment: I'm sure this will be very slow.
@Simon Not sure why you think I'm looking for file hashing.

Comment: @Spacemonkey - use the `HashSet<String>` is have personally used to find duplicates in txt file of filesize 500 MB it just took couple of seconds!

Comment: ok thanks for the answer, I will benchmark and see, I'm sure it's faster than normal string comparison

Comment: @Spacemonkey You say "script". I assumed you meant a file.. not a string.

Comment: @Simon I didn't know that "script" means a file... also I said in the title I'm comparing strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use HashSet like below

```
        string uniqueCode= "ABC";
        string uniqueCode1 = "XYZ";
        string uniqueCode2 = "ABC";
        HashSet<string> uniqueList = new HashSet<string>();

       uniqueList.Add(uniqueCode);
       uniqueList.Add(uniqueCode1);
       uniqueList.Add(uniqueCode2);
```

If you see the **Count** of **uniqueList** you will 2. so ABC will not be there two times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashSet. a hash-set is guaranteed to never contain duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Store the script along with its hash:

```
class ScriptData
{
  public ScriptData(string script)
  {
    this.ScriptHash=script.GetHashCode();
    this.Script=script;
  }

  public int ScriptHash{get;private set;}
  public string Script{get;private set;}
}
```

Then, whenever you need to check if your new random script is unique just take the hash code of the new script and seach all your `ScriptData` instances for any with the same hash code. If you dont find any you know your new random script is unique. If you do find some then they **may** be the same and you'll have to compare the actual text of the scripts in order to see if they're identical.

Comment: Are you implying the `GetHashCode` method might be a bottle neck?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you're going to keep recomputing it then you might as well store it away somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can store each generated `string` in a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx).

For each new string you will call the method `Contains` which runs in O(1) complexity. This is an easy way to decide if the new generated string was generated before.